# IntelliJ, I can't import groovy files

Tags: class, groovy, import, intellij-idea

[image: error]

Ok so I can't import groovy.class files and now my code doesnt work anymore when i want to run it, does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Your question was likely closed because you aren't providing information on when it DID last work, giving us the information necessary to see what was **different** between when it did work, and now. Your response to the answer, "Still didn't work", doesn't help the people here that want to help you - you've got to do the work of giving us all the information if you expect a useful answer. You seem to imply, with the statement "doesn't work anymore" that you had it working at one time. Tell us about that configuration, and what's different.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the module is referencing the Groovy global library and that the global library is configured correctly.

[image: Module Dependencies]
[image: Global Libraries]